# Importing class from git - unable to resolve class

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy

I am constructing a Shared Library which I want to have class definitions, such as:

```
package com.org.pipeline.aws

String family
JsonObject taskDefinition

class TaskDefinition {

  def getTaskDefinition(family) {
    def jsonSlurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
    def object = slurper.parseText(
      sh(returnStdout: true,
        script: "aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition ${family}"
      )
    )
    return assert object instanceof Map
    taskDefinition = object["taskDefinition"]
  }
}
```

And I am importing it via a separate git repository

```
library identifier: 'jenkins-shared-libraries@master', retriever: modernSCM(
  [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
   remote: 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org.net/smar/jenkins-shared-libraries.git',
   credentialsId: 'jenkins-bitbucket-ssh-private-key'])

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def z = new com.org.pipeline.aws.TaskDefinition()
                    withAWS(region: 'ap-southeast-1', credentials: 'awsId') {
                        z.getTaskDefinition("web-taskdef")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it keeps giving me this error: `unable to resolve class com.org.pipeline.aws.TaskDefinition()`. Any idea why?

Comment: might be it's because of - Using classes from the src/ directory is also possible, but trickier. Whereas the @Library annotation prepares the “classpath” of the script prior to compilation, by the time a library step is encountered the script has already been compiled. Therefore you cannot import or otherwise “statically” refer to types from the library . from [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#loading-libraries-dynamically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Loading Shared library dynamically](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#loading-libraries-dynamically) is a bit tricky to make your expected class available during the class loader before compilation of the pipeline, because of :

*(copied from Jenkins documentation)*
Using classes from the src/ directory is also possible, but trickier. Whereas the @Library annotation prepares the “classpath” of the script prior to compilation, by the time a library step is encountered the script has already been compiled. Therefore you cannot import

But you can make your method static and access from the pipeline this way, like the below example:

The **shared library** folder structure looks like:

```
.
├── src
│   └── net
│       └── samittutorial
│           ├── Math.groovy
```

**Math.groovy**

```
package net.samittutorial
class Math implements Serializable {
    def pipeline 
    Math(def pipeline) {
        this.pipeline = pipeline
    }
    Math() {

    }
    def writeAndDisplayContent(int x, int y) {
        pipeline.sh """
            echo ${x+y} > ${pipeline.env.WORKSPACE}/result.txt
            cat ${pipeline.env.WORKSPACE}/result.txt
        """
    }

    static def substract(int x, int y) {
        return x - y
    }

    static def add(int x, int y) {
        return x + y
    }

    static def info() {
        return "Hello from Math class"
    }
}
```

**Jenkinsfile**

```
def d = library identifier: 'jenkins-shared-libraries@question/stackoverflow', retriever: modernSCM([
        $class: 'GitSCMSource',
        remote: 'https://github.com/samitkumarpatel/jenkins-shared-libs.git'
]) net.samittutorial

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('debug') {
            steps {
                script {
                    //info
                    println d.Math.info()

                    //add
                    println d.Math.add(5,5) 

                    // writeAndDisplayContent(1,2) is non static , it will not work like d.Math(this).writeAndDisplayContent(1,2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But If you load your library like [this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#using-libraries) Jenkins pipeline will have no restriction or limitation, you can go ahead like below example and use your class where ever you want on your pipeline flow.

**Shared Library structure** and **Math.groovy** will remain the same like above example

The **Jenkinsfile** will look like:

```
@Library('jenkins-shared-library') _

import net.samittutorial.Math

pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('debug') {
            steps {
                echo "Hello World"
                script {
                    def math = new Math(this)
                    println math.add(4,5)
                    math.writeAndDisplayContent(1,2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```