# Use multi-method global variables in Jenkins Shared Libraries

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-shared-libraries

Consider this groovy file in a repo that is loaded as shared library in Jenkins:

```
/ vars
|
--- Utility.groovy

// Utility.groovy

def funcA() { ... }

def funcB() { ... }
```

And in the Jenkinsfile:

```
// Jenkinsfile

@Library('LibName') _

pipeline {
...
steps {
   script {
      def util = new Utility()
      util.funcA()
   }
 }
}
```

This works fine. But if i try to load the library dynamically:

```
// Jenkinsfile

pipeline {
   ...
   steps {
       script {
          library 'LibName'
          def util = new Utility()
       }

    }


}
```

That doesn't work...

Can someone explain this with respect to this quote from the documentation:

The documentation of Shared Libraries in Jenkins says:

> Internally, scripts in the vars directory are instantiated on-demand as singletons. This allows multiple methods to be defined in a single .groovy file for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Loading a Jenkins Shared Library dynamically has some limitation and challenges because of:

*Using classes from the src/ directory is also possible, but trickier. Whereas the @Library annotation prepares the “classpath” of the script prior to compilation, by the time a library step is encountered the script has already been compiled. Therefore you cannot import or otherwise “statically” refer to types from the library.* which is explained [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#loading-libraries-dynamically)

And it seems this question is kind of similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63948975/importing-class-from-git-unable-to-resolve-class/65942947#65942947) one.