# Can a Groovy source file in Jenkins' Shared Library access a method from a global variable?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, cicd, jenkins-shared-libraries

Can a Groovy source file in Jenkins' Shared Library access a method from a global variable?

my Shared Library structure is:

```
(root)
+- src                     # Groovy source files
|   +- org
|       +- foo
|           +- CallMethodFromVars.groovy  # for org.foo.CallMethodFromGlobalVars.groovy class
+- vars
|   +- foo.groovy          # for global 'foo' variable
```

In my class `src.org.foo.CallMethodFromVars` I would like to access a method `call(arg)` in `vars.foo.groovy`

src.org.foo.CallMethodFromVars:

```
class CallMethodFromVars  {
    String run(){
         //TODO call method vars.foo.groovy.call() here
    }
}
```

vars.foo.groovy:

```
def call(arg) {
   doSomething()
}
```

My research and attempts at solving this so far have failed. Some of the things I tried:

- `import var.*`; `foo.groovy.call(arg)`
- `def method = this.class.classLoader.loadClass('vars.foo'); method.call(arg)`
- `def engine = new GroovyScriptEngine("/path-to-library/vars/foo.groovy"); engine.run('call', [arg])`
- `def method = library.vars.foo; method.call(arg)`
- `def method libraryContext.getVariable("foo"); method.call(arg)`
- `method = System.getenv('foo'); method.call(arg)`
- I tried all the above with `method()` instead of `method.call(arg)`

Comment: In general you need to pass the Script Context to you class in order to access vars methods or any other built in Jenkins methods. Take a look at the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66092978/13110835) it has a very good explanation for your case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I came across that thread before. Unfortunately it does not answer my question. It shows how to run a class from src folder in Jenkinsfile. However it does not show how to access a class from src folder in a script that is placed in vars folder.

Comment: In that case use it like you will use it in a pipeline, in your var file import the relevant function `import src.org.foo.CallMethodFromVars` and then use it inside the code.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake replying you, I meant the opposite, to run a function from vars in src, and I tried the import, which I listed in my attempts at solving this

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/Ableton/python-pipeline-utils/blob/master/src/com/ableton/VirtualEnv.groovy) project, it is a python virtual env implementation for Jenkins. Take a look at the `script` object in the `VirtualEnv` class and how he uses it to call Jenkins defined methods like `sh` and so. In a similar way you can call your vars methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. As stated in the first answer, the question is somehow addressed already but let me give here very simple example basing on your code.
To be more precise: we have 2 kinds of libraries here: objective library written as class and static library written like method. You want to call static library from inside objective library.

The key to solve the problem is to pass script object from pipeline itself. I name it `parentScript` here:

```
class CallMethodFromVars  {

    def parentScript

    CallMethodFromVars(parentScript) {
        this.parentScript = parentScript
    }

    String run(arg){
        parentScript.foo(arg)
    }
}
```

After this, you need to call the objective library from the pipeline, for example like this (you need to configure library in Jenkins to be accessible under specific name e.g. 'objective-lib'):

```
def lib = library('objective-lib').org.foo
def instance = lib.CallMethodFromVars.new(this) // 'this' becomes parentScript inside objective library
instance.run('some args')
```

Objective library is called from pipeline by creating the instance and then calling method of that instance which in turn calls static library.

Comment: if I have multiple scripts unser `vars`, will they all be loaded with `def instance = lib.CallMethodFromVars.new(this)` ?

Comment: Yes, if you call them explicitly like `foo` in the example. They also need to be available in pipeline: either as implicit library or called explicitly by `library 'static-lib'`. Both ways need jenkins configuration to make 'static-lib' library be available. It is described here: [https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)